# How Can I refresh my Datagrid on WPF automatically for every 1 minute?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, refresh

I want to be able do refresh my datagrid, because I am updating my table on my database datagrid and want to see the changes in grid , is there any way of automatically updating datagrid for every 1 minute?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`DataGrid.Items.Refresh()` will refresh the items.  You can then use a [timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.71).aspx) to run every minute to force the refresh

[Here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/WPfTimer09292009090518AM/WPfTimer.aspx) is an example of implementing a timer to update a ListBox which you can adapt for your purpose.

Comment: Indigo Delta, Thank u I am new to wpf , I ll research how to use timer as I havent used before.

Comment: timers and datagrid.items.refresh is not related to WPF, it is core .net framework :D

Comment: Tks Mark I didnt know!!Though was related to wpf :P

Comment: ` public void RefreshScreen()
        {
            System.Timers.Timer myTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
            myTimer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(myTimer_Elapsed);
            myTimer.Interval = 1000;
            myTimer.Enabled = true;
        }

        public void myTimer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            DisplayInGrid();
        }`

Comment: I am having this exception The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.Any Idea?!

Comment: @Indigo Delta Thank you your LitBox example gave me right direction.Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: I added a link to an example that might help.  If you are running the timer in a thread other than the UI thread then you will need to look at Invoking the call on the UI object.

Comment: @ Indigo Example link gave me right direction and my problem now is solved thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Going forward you can use `ObservableCollection` to bind the grid so that you can avoid manual refreshes.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using [DispatcherTimer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer?view=netframework-4.8) which simplified some threading issues for me:

```
    private static DispatcherTimer _dataUpdateTimer = null;

    private ObservableCollection<Item> _items;

    public ObservableCollection<Item> Items
    {
        get { return _items; }
        set
        {
            if (_items == value)
                return;
            _items = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Items));
        }
    }

    private void SetupDataUpdateTimer()
    {
        _dataUpdateTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
        _dataUpdateTimer.Tick += OnDataUpdateEvent;
        _dataUpdateTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10000);
        _dataUpdateTimer.Start();
    }

    private void OnDataUpdateEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Items = ... add or remove items
        // ...      
    }
```

When I was previously just using a basic `Timer` I was getting this error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException
  HResult=0x80131509
  Message=The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.
  Source=WindowsBase
  StackTrace:
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.VerifyAccess()
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.GetValue(DependencyProperty dp)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.get_SelectedValue()
   at ...
   at System.Timers.Timer.MyTimerCallback(Object state)
```